# Deployment to AppService doesn't recognize environment variables

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have my dotnet core API deployed to Azure AppService. When it runs in debug mode locally, I am getting the environment variables from local.settings.json/debug and it works fine. I get the connection string there and a few more items. After I deploy to AppService the application is not able to load the environment variables. I even try to put them in appsettings still it doesn't pick them up. Anyone can assist with this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to add the environment variables to the configuration tab in the Azure App Service? The `local.settings.json` file only houses environment variables only when you run the application locally.

[image: Click here to find where the configuration tab is located at in an Azure App Service]

Comment: What about the local.settings.json? I already have there the environment variables, according to microsoft documentation this is where I need to put the variables for different envs.

Comment: This is true when you are locally running your application. When you deploy the code to Azure App Service, you would need to add the environment variables in the configuration settings tab.